# VBA loop that will read from different tables

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to write a VBA that will loop through 128 different tables that are linked into my access database from 128 different excel files and take the data and place it into one table. Each table is the same just a different TS. I was able to write this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_GTAS ( SF133_Rpt_Line, LineDescription, LineAmt, 
TS ) SELECT [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F1, [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F2, 
[75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F3, '75-XXXX-XXXX' AS TS FROM [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133] 
GROUP BY [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F1, [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F2, 
[75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F3, '75-XXXX-XXXX';"
```

I just need to take that somehow and have it pull for each of my tables.

All of my tables have the same naming convention with either XX, XXXX or X after the 75-.
Any help would be very appreciated!!

Thanks!

edit:

Full VBA code:

```
Public Function GTAS()

   Dim SBRLink2017 As DAO.Database
   Set SBRLink2017 = CurrentDb


   Dim delSQL As String
   Dim updSQL As String
   Dim str1SQL As String

   DoCmd.SetWarnings False

   delSQL = "DELETE tbl_GTAS.* FROM tbl_GTAS';"

   DoCmd.RunSQL (delSQL)

   str1SQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_GTAS ( SF133_Rpt_Line, LineDescription, LineAmt, TS ) SELECT [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F1, [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F2, [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F3, '75-XXXX-XXXX' AS TS FROM [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133] GROUP BY [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F1, [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F2, [75-XXXX-XXXX_NEW SF 133].F3, '75-XXXX-XXXX';"

   DoCmd.RunSQL str1SQL

   updSQL = "UPDATE Tbl_GTAS SET Tbl_GTAS.TS_SF133_Rpt_Line = [TS] & '_' & [SF133_Rpt_Line];"

   DoCmd.RunSQL (updSQL)

   DoCmd.SetWarnings True

 End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested and double-check that I included all parenthesis as needed. I think I did:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs

    ' ignore system and temporary tables
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then

        Dim sTable As String
        sTable = tdf.Name

        Dim strSQL
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_GTAS ( SF133_Rpt_Line, LineDescription, LineAmt, TS)" & _
            "SELECT T.F1, T.F2,T.F3, '" & Replace(sTable, "_NEW SF 133", "") & "' AS TS " & _
            "FROM " & sTable & " AS T" & _
            "GROUP BY T.F1, T.F2, T.F3,'" & Replace(sTable, "_NEW SF 133", "") & "';"

        'do what you will with SQL

    End If

Next
```

Comment: I updated my post to include the whole code I am using. Where would this go into that code? And I have a table with all the TS listed out I assume that I would need to replace sTable with that table name? THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: @AF15 - These are all additional and separate questions from the original. However, you can place this loop where the `str1SQL` statement is, as I see it. I have no idea what *"all the TS listed out"* means, so I cannot help you there.

Comment: This is perfect and works great. One question though. How do I get it to return just the TS not the "_New SF 133" part too. Thanks!

Comment: @AF15 - `Replace(sTable, "_NEW SF 133", "")` or `Replace(tdf.Name,"_NEW SF 133","")`